# Jasmine Dom element test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm new to writing tests and I'm trying to figure out how to test if after a click the right content is loaded. I'm testing a directive, but the loaded content in the center panel. I'm first firing a click event and then I try to compile the loaded content and check if the title is the one I expected (Test).

What I'm getting as an error is

> "Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined"

Any idea why and how to fix the test?

```
describe('someSelector', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        module(function($provide) {
            $provide.decorator('$timeout', function($delegate) {
                var flush = $delegate.flush;
                var $timeout = jasmine.createSpy('$timeout').and.callFake($delegate);
                $timeout.flush = flush;
                return $timeout;
            });
        });
        this.injectDependencies('$compile',
            '$scope',
            '$httpBackend',
            'renderTemplateAndAppendToDom',
            'renderTemplate',
            '$timeout');

        this.render = this.renderTemplateAndAppendToDom;
        this.dirStr = '<div class="some-navigator" vx-view="history[history.currentIndex].naviView"></div>';
        this.viewStr = '<center-panel></center-panel>';
    });

    describe('when navigating to an object', function () {
        beforeEach(function () {
            this.$httpBackend.resetExpectations();
        });

        it('should load the correct content', function () {
            var dir = this.$compile(this.dirStr)(this.$scope);
            dir.find('span.some-navigator-label [title="Test"]').click();
            dir.remove();
            var view = this.$compile(this.viewStr)(this.$scope);
            var contentCheck = view.find('span.titlebar-text');
            expect(contentCheck[0].innerHTML).toEqual('Test');
            this.$scope.$destroy();
            view.remove();
        });
    });
});
```